# Enter key behave like arrow keys in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, jqwidget

I use jQwidget in my application. When I press Enter I want it to behave like arrow keys (navigate to the left on table's cell. )

```js
($('#documentDetail') as any).jqxGrid({
  handlekeyboardnavigation: function (event, row) {
          var key = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : 0;
          if (key == 13) {
             //navigate like arrow keys
          }
}
```

Comment: A simple work around is, if you already have a logic of left arrow key in your code, just change the value of key from 13 to the left arrow key...

Comment: Nope, I don't have any function for arrow keys , It's just for JQwidget

Comment: So can you show us a minimal reproducible example in stackblitz Or some other code sandbox so we can take a look at and help out